# Can some one give a step-by-step computation for an empirical distribution with this concrete example

Tags: r, empirical-cumulative-distr-fn

This [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/424115/) gives this formula to compute the empirical distribution:

\begin{equation}
\hat{p}(x) = \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m \delta(x - x^{(i)}) \tag{3.25}
\end{equation}

I am trying to compute this with a concrete example:

```
set.seed(5)
x <- rnorm(12)
x
```

`x` stores a list of 12 variables that generated from a normal distribution.

```
 [1] -0.84085548  1.38435934 -1.25549186  0.07014277  1.71144087 -0.60290798
 [7] -0.47216639 -0.63537131 -0.28577363  0.13810822  1.22763034 -0.80177945
```

Calling `ecdf`

```
ecdf(x)
```

gives this output:

```
Empirical CDF 
Call: ecdf(x)
 x[1:12] = -1.2555, -0.84086, -0.80178,  ..., 1.3844, 1.7114
```

can some one gives a step by step computation for this empirical distribution with this concrete example

Comment: $\hat p$ is the empirical probability *measure,* not its CDF.  For the relationship between the two please see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/73623.

Answer (score 3):

Although that post didn't say so, it was using "$\delta$" in the sense of an abstract mathematical object that one can integrate.  Its rules are especially simple: for any function $f,$ the integral of "$\delta(x)f(x)\mathrm{d}x$" over any set $\mathcal R$ equals $f(0)$ if $0\in \mathcal R$ and otherwise the integral is zero.

#### Background

This obviously is not a Riemann integral, nor is it a Lebesgue integral: it is a "generalized function" that extends the operation of integration.  The concept it is generalizing is that of the integral-as-functional.  That is, the rule that associates with any function $f$ its integral over a fixed region $\mathcal R$ is a "function of a function"--a *functional*--that enjoys some nice properties.  In particular, integration is *linear*: the integral of a linear combination of functions is the same linear combination of their integrals.  $\delta$ is one of the simplest examples of a linear functional that cannot be expressed as a (Riemann or Lebesgue) integral.

For any number $a,$ we can also "shift" $\delta$ by defining $$\int_\mathcal{R}\delta_a(x)f(x)\mathrm{d}x = f(a).$$

This permits us to abuse notation by *defining*

$$\delta(x-a) = \delta_a(x)$$

because it enables us (somewhat mindlessly) to apply the substitution $y=x-a$ in the integral, giving

$$\int\delta(x-a)f(x)\mathrm{d}x = \int \delta(y) f(y+a)\mathrm{d}y = f(0+a)=f(a)$$

as intended.  In particular, letting $f(x)=1$ be the constant function, we have

$$\int_\mathcal{R}\delta_a(x)\mathrm{d}x = \left\{\matrix{1&\text{if }a\in \mathcal{R} \\ 0&\text{otherwise}}\right.\tag{*}$$

#### Application

By definition, the value of the CDF $F(t)$ of any distribution $\hat p$ is obtained by integrating that distribution up to the number $t,$ which we can perform by using the linearity property:

$$F(t) = \int_{-\infty}^t \hat{p}(x)\mathrm{d}x = \int_{-\infty}^t \sum_{i=1}^m\frac{1}{m}\delta(x-x^{(i)})\mathrm{d}x = \sum_{i=1}^m \frac{1}{m} \int_{-\infty}^t \delta_{x^{(i)}}\mathrm{d}x.$$

The integrals in the sum are immediately obtained from the basic relation $(*)$ above: they are zero except for the $i$ with $x^{(i)}\in (-\infty, t],$ where they equal $1.$  The result can be written

$$F(t) = \sum_{i\mid x^{(i)} \le t} \frac{1}{m}.$$

There is a term $1/m$ for each data value less than or equal to $t.$  Thus,

> $F(t) = k/t$ where $k$ counts the number of data values less than or equal to $t.$

The graph of $F$ therefore consists of horizontal segments that jump by some multiple of $1/m$ at each data value $x^{(i)}.$  The multiple is given by the number of times $x^{(i)}$ appears in the dataset.  See the figure below for an example.

#### Computation

An optimal algorithm for computing $F$ begins by efficiently sorting the $n$ data values.  For instance, if the $n=5$ data are $1, 3, 2, 5, 3$ then in sorted order they are $1,2,3,3,5.$  The next step is to combine repeated values, summarizing them by their counts. Augment this list with starting and ending values $(-\infty,0)$ (for index $i=0$) and $(\infty,0).$  Finally, compute the cumulative sums $n_i$ of the counts and divide them by $n.$  Generally, write $(z_i, n_i/n)$ for the value $z_i$ and cumulative count $n_i$ at position $i$ in the list.  For the example data, this list is

$$(-\infty, 0), (1,1/5), (2,2/5), (3,4/5), (5,5/5), (\infty, 5).\tag{**}$$

Creating this data structure takes at most $O(n \log n)$ time and $O(n)$ storage.

**Given $t,$** use a binary search to find the unique $i$ for which $z_i \ge t$ and $z_{i+1}\lt t.$  Return the value of $n_i/n.$  This requires $O(\log n)$ time.

**Given an ascending sequence of arguments $t,$** start with a binary search and then search forward through the list with each successive value.  For very large sequences of length $N \gg n,$ this takes $O(\log(n)+N)$ time.

**To plot the graph of $F,$** draw a horizontal half-open line segment from $z_i$ to $z_{i+1}$ at height $n_i/n$ for all but the last index $i.$  Each segment includes its left endpoint but not its right endpoint.  This takes at most $O(n)$ time (even accounting for the clipping to the plotting window).

#### Example

In `R`, the output of `ecdf` is an *object* consisting of this list (or its logical equivalent).  What is reported in the question is merely `R`'s way of *printing* this object.  It's not terribly useful.  The help for `ecdf` says you can find the data for this object in its environment.  For instance,

```
obj <- ecdf(c(1,3,2,5,3))
```

stores this object in `obj` which you can inspect *via*

```
as.list(environment(obj))

$`nobs`
[1] 5
$x
[1] 1 2 3 5
$y
[1] 0.2 0.4 0.8 1.0
$method
[1] 2
$yleft
[1] 0
$yright
[1] 1
$f
[1] 0
```

By comparing this to the abstract data structure $(**)$ it should now be obvious, even to those who do not use `R`, what most of these values represent.  (`f` and `method` are used by the parent class for approximating functions in more flexible ways.)

**The clearest way to inspect an `ecdf` object is to plot it:**

```
plot(obj)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The formula you quoted is empirical generalized PDF, and the `R` function `ecdf` gives you the generalized integral of it, which is the empirical CDF (i.e. cumulative distribution function). Specifically, `ecdf` returns a function object that you can call, e.g. a usage may be as follows:

```
f = ecdf(x)
f(-1)
```

As the [explanation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.1/topics/ecdf) notes, empirical CDF is just a step function simply calculates the following probability for any given $x$:
$$\hat{F_X}(x)=\frac{\text{Number of data points that is } \leq x}{m}$$